# how to make a richedit's text continue on the next page with fast report in delphi xe3?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, fastreport

I am using Delphi xe3 and Fastreport to generate documents.
Currently i have the following components in the report:

- 1 Page
- 1 Rich Edit
- 1 Picture

The picture is the page footer, and the richedit is the rest of the page.

I am struggling to get the rich edit to continue on the next page of the report when the text extends over the page's lenght.

As the report can be anything from 1 page to 5, depending on the person using the software i need to prepare it for more than 1 page.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 2):

Set the property stretched of your Masterdata band containing the TfrxRichView to true.
 The property StretchMode of your TfrxRichview has to be set to smActualHeight or smMaxHeight.